# How can I make an instance of a custom class return bool?

Tags: c#

`someList` here will return a `bool` value:

```
List<int> someList = new List<int>();
if(someList) { }
```

And in the line below, the compiler will warn me saying that I cannot implicitly convert type `CustomType` to `bool`:

```
CustomType t = new CustomType();
if(customType) {}
```

So, how do I get the instances of my class to return `bool`? Or even something else, like an `integer` or a `float`?

Comment: I can't begin to understand what you're trying to check here. What are you expecting the bool value to represent ?

Comment: I mean t could be null, right? I could've done something like :

    CustomType t = null;

then check

    if(t) {} ...

Comment: If you want to check whether it's null use something like if (customType == null)

Comment: I know how to check if it's null with "==" operator. That's not what I'm asking though.

Comment: I think you looking for a factory method that returns a bool and has an out parameter of your custom type.

Comment: And those who vote down, could be less mean <.<

Comment: in your example, you are not checking an instance, but the class (the type) itself. that can't be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your CustomType class, you could define an implicit conversion operator to bool :

```
public static implicit operator bool(CustomType custom)
{
    return true; // Place your logic here
}
```

Defining implicit conversion operators should be done with care to avoid unmaintainable code. I would advise you to consider having a method or a property inside your CustomType class, that return a boolean based on some logic :

```
public bool IsValid { get { return true; // Place your logic here } }
```

Comment: It can't be done inside List class, of course.

Comment: @Nik if you want to use it only for null check, be aware - creating custom operator may lead to unreadable code - when cast is unclear and not intuitive.